# Форматирование вокруг ^ CLion

Tags: c++, c, форматирование, clion, format

Почему `CLion` форматирует этот код

```
int main() {
    int y = 1^2;
}
```

в этот

```
int main() {
    int y = 1 ^2;
}
```

В настройках указано, что должен быть пробел вокруг `bitwise operators`. Это баг или можно где-то поменять это?

`&` и `|` форматирует нормально.

Comment: Может вам clang format настроить лучше?

Comment: @punchel у вас работает в `clang-format` это?

Comment: Может вам clang format настроить лучше?

Comment: Пока это не является ответов на вопрос. Попробуйте дописать, как именно нужно настроить `clang format` и тогда ответ станет полезным. Что изменить ответ - кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1166244/edit) под ним.